# In flutter Detect automatically if sms is received or not by my app

Tags: flutter, dart, sms-gateway

I’m doing a project where I need to check the SMS gateway service. That’s why I want to send an SMS to my phone through an SMS gateway. In this part, I want my app to detect automatically if my phone received that message what o sent or not.

I’m trying to do it using flutter. But couldn’t find proper resources.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [sms package](https://pub.dev/packages/sms) to do this. Receiving an SMS will look like this:

```
  import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

  void main() {
    SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
    receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => print(msg.body));
  }
```